# I Sum All Values But Why It's Not Working For All Dynamic Total Fields

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.7

I'm using `Laravel 5.7` & `VueJs 2.5.*` ...

**IN SHORT:** When i enter values i get the sum in Total field, but when i add items row dynamically it's not working for other items row, it's just working for the first row.

**DISCRIPTION:** I have some input fields of `Taxes_Breakup`, i need to sum all of them and show in `Total_Tax_BreakUp` field. In my `TicketInvoiceItems` i have `Taxes_Breakup` fields and a `Total_Taxes_Breakup` field, when i enter all values i get the sum in `Total_Taxes_Breakup`, but when i add `TicketInvoiceItems` fields dynamically, other `Total_Tax_BreakUp` fields in `TicketInvoiceItems` is as same as the the first `Total_Tax_BreakUp` field.Below is an image for better understanding.Thank You.

Here is my `HTML` code:

```html
<tr v-for="(ticketInvoiceItem, key) in form.ticketInvoiceItems" :key="key">
  <!--Passenger Name-->
  <td>
    <input v-model="ticketInvoiceItem.passenger_name" size="40" type="text" name="passenger_name" class="table-control form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('passenger_name') }">
  </td>

  <!-------------------Taxes BreakUps------------------->
  <input v-model="ticketInvoiceItem.tax_SB" id="tax_SB" type="number" name="tax_SB" placeholder="SB" class="table-control form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('tax_SB') }">

  <input v-model="ticketInvoiceItem.tax_SRP" id="tax_SRP" type="number" name="tax_SRP" placeholder="SRP" class="table-control form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('tax_SRP') }">
  <!-------------------AND OTHER TAXES------------------->


  <!-------------------Total Taxes Break Up------------------->
  <td>
    <input :value="totalTax" id="total_tax_breakup" type="number" size="10" name="total_tax_breakup" class="table-control form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('total_tax_breakup') }">
  </td>
</tr>
```

My VueJs `data()`:

```js
data() {
  return {
    editmode: true,
    ticketInvoices: {},
    form: new Form({
      id: "",
      vendor_id: "",
      ticket_invoice_no: "",
      ticket_invoice_date: "",
      ticket_invoice_grand_total: "",

      ticketInvoiceItems: [{
        id: "",
        ticket_invoice_id: "",
        passenger_name: "",
        sector: "",
        tax_SB: 0,
        tax_SRP: 0,
        tax_YQ: 0,
        tax_RG: 0,
        total_tax_breakup: 0,
      }]
    })
  };
},
```

My `computed:` code:

```js
computed: {
  totalTax() {
    let calTaxTotal =
      parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[0].tax_SB) +
      parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[0].tax_SRP) +
      parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[0].tax_YQ) +
      parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[0].tax_RG);

    this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[0].total_tax_breakup = calTaxTotal;

    return calTaxTotal;

  }
},
```

[image]

Comment: You had better separate code inside `v-for` to a custom component. It's easier.

Comment: I'm new at this, so i didn't understand what you said until and unless you elaborate in a easy way, also my English is not so good..... BTW Thanks Brother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your computed property.  All of your indexes are at 0 or the first row of your table.  If you want to add up more than one row you need to pass the index into your totalTax.  So a computed property is not the best choice.  Turn it into a method instead and pass the index (or key) into the method.

```
<input :value="getTotalTaxes(key)"
                       id="total_tax_breakup"
                       type="number" size="10"
                       name="total_tax_breakup"
                       class="table-control form-control">
```

Method

```
      methods: {
        /**
         * The index parameter is the current row that you are working on  
         * @param index
         * @returns {number}
         */
        getTotalTaxes(index) {
            let calTaxTotal =
                parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[index].tax_SB) +
                parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[index].tax_SRP) +
                parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[index].tax_YQ) +
                parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[index].tax_RG);

            this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[index].total_tax_breakup = calTaxTotal;

            return calTaxTotal;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Brother..... Can you get me help me out form this one too ? @Shawn 
Stack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998040/i-need-to-edit-my-invoice-but-how-to-fill-invoice-items-data-in-it

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr v-for="(ticketInvoiceItem, key) in form.ticketInvoiceItems" :key="key">
  <!--Passenger Name-->
  <td>
    <input v-model="ticketInvoiceItem[key].passenger_name" size="40" type="text" name="passenger_name" class="table-control form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('passenger_name') }" @change="totalTax(key)">
  </td>

  <!-------------------Taxes BreakUps------------------->
  <input v-model="ticketInvoiceItem[key].tax_SB" id="tax_SB" type="number" name="tax_SB" placeholder="SB" class="table-control form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('tax_SB') }" @change="totalTax(key)">

  <input v-model="ticketInvoiceItem[key].tax_SRP" id="tax_SRP" type="number" name="tax_SRP" placeholder="SRP" class="table-control form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('tax_SRP') }"  @change="totalTax(key)">
  <!-------------------AND OTHER TAXES------------------->


  <!-------------------Total Taxes Break Up------------------->
  <td>
    <input :value="totalTax" id="total_tax_breakup" type="number" size="10" name="total_tax_breakup" class="table-control form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('total_tax_breakup') }">
  </td>
</tr>
```

for me i will use `@change` instead of `computed` 
put the code below in `methods`

```
totalTax(key) {
    let calTaxTotal =
      parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[key].tax_SB) +
      parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[key].tax_SRP) +
      parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[key].tax_YQ) +
      parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[key].tax_RG);

    this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[key].total_tax_breakup = calTaxTotal;

    return calTaxTotal;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Brother for your support but i accepted the above answer, i think it's the easy one....can you do me a favor ?

Can you get me help me out form this issue ? @VernonJianHao

Stak: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998040/i-need-to-edit-my-invoice-but-how-to-fill-invoice-items-data-in-it