# How To Get The Sum Of All Fares

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using `Laravel 5.7` & `VueJs 2.5.*` ...

I want to get the sum of all fares in my `TotalFares`. I was playing around but didn't get any success...

Here is my `Fares` `<Input>`:

```html
<tr v-for="(ticketInvoiceItem, key) in form.ticketInvoiceItems" :key="key">
  <td>
    <input v-model.number="ticketInvoiceItem.fares" type="number" size="10" name="fares" class="table-control form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('fares') }">
    <has-error :form="form" field="fares"></has-error>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Here is my `TotalFares` `<input>`:

```html
<tfoot class="tfoot">
  <tr>
    <td class="table-amount">

      <input :value="getFareTotal()" type="text" name="ticket_invoice_fares_total" class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('ticket_invoice_fares_total') }">

    </td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```

My `data()` in `VueJs`:

```js
data() {
  return {
    ticketInvoices: {},
    vendors: null,
    form: new Form({
      id: "",
      vendor_id: "",
      ticket_invoice_no: "",
      ticket_invoice_date: "",
      ticket_invoice_fares_total: "",

      ticketInvoiceItems: [{
        id: "",
        ticket_invoice_id: "",
        passenger_name: "",
        fares: 0,
      }]
    })
  }
},
```

I tried to get `FaresTotal` something Like this but failed:

```js
getFareTotal() {
  let calFareTotal =
    parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[key].fares) +
    parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoice.ticket_invoice_fares_total);

  this.form.ticketInvoice.ticket_invoice_fares_total = calFareTotal;

  return calFareTotal;
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getFareTotal() {
  let sum = 0
  this.form.ticketInvoiceItems.forEach(i=> sum+=i.fares);
  console.log(sum)
}
```

ticketInvoiceItems is a collection. So you have to iterate about it.

Comment: Without StackOverFlow and brothers like you we can't survice..... Can you help me out from this one too ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998040/i-need-to-edit-my-invoice-but-how-to-fill-invoice-items-data-in-it

Comment: @A.Lau Sorry i forgot :D