# Why Can't I See My GrandTotal In My View?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using `Laravel 5.7` & `VueJs 2.5.*` ...

I want to display `GrandTotal` on my view table, but i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Where i'm displaying `GrandTotal`:

```html
<tr v-for="ctInvoice in ctInvoices" :key="ctInvoice.id">
  <td>{{ formatPrice(ctInvoice.ct_invoice_grand_total) }}</td>
</tr>
```

My `VueJs` `data()`:

```js
data() {
    return {
      ctInvoices: {},
      customers: null,
      form: new Form({
        id: "",
        customer_id: "",
        ct_invoice_no: "",
        ct_invoice_date: "",
        ct_invoice_fares_total: 0,
        ct_invoice_taxes_grand_total: 0,
        ct_invoice_grand_total: 0,

        ctInvoiceItems: [{
          id: "",
          ct_invoice_id: "",
          ct_passenger_name: "",
          ct_fares: 0,
          ct_total_tax_breakup: 0,
          ct_sub_total: 0
        }]
      })
    };
```

Format Amount with this `method()`:

```js
formatPrice(value) {
  let val = (value / 1).toFixed().replace(".", ".");
  return val.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","); //75.674,00
},
```

Image For Better Understanding:
[image]

One item output from `ctInvoices` array

> ctInvoices:Array[20] 
>   0:Object 
>   created_at:"2018-10-27 15:13:06" 
>   ct_Invoice_date:"2018-10-31" 
>   ct_Invoice_fares_total:"600.00" 
>   ct_Invoice_grand_total:"1000.00" 
>   ct_Invoice_grand_total_words:null 
>   ct_Invoice_taxes_grand_total:"400.00" 
>   ct_Invoice_terms:null 
>   ct_invoice_items:Array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRpMe.png) 
>   ct_invoice_no:"111-222-333" 
>   customer:Object 
>   customer_id:3 
>   id:22 
>   updated_at:"2018-10-27 15:13:06"

Comment: why are you doing `replace(".", ".");`?

Comment: I don't know i just want to display my value in a money format, so i raise question and a guy gave me `formatMoney` `method()`.

Comment: could you refer me to that question ?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Here it is, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208012/how-do-i-format-currencies-in-a-vue-component

Comment: in your case you're doing `let val = (value / 1).toFixed().replace(".", ".");` but in the given question there's `let val = (value / 1).toFixed().replace(".", ",");`

Comment: yeah because i want to display my value like this `40,000` not like this `40.000` thats my i did this : `let val = (value / 1).toFixed().replace(".", ".");`

Comment: look good at your code, you're replacing the dot by another dot

Comment: Let me tell you one this i have to `ticketInvoices` just like `ctInvoices`, all data is same and `formatMoney` method is working perfectly there, i can see my value is Money format, I'm doing same in `ctInvoices`, i don't know why it's not working in `ctInvoices`.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim can you help me out with this issue, i'm not able to resolve this since many days: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998040/why-cant-i-see-my-invoice-items-when-i-edit-my-invoice

Comment: before going to the old question, i invite you to look at your code `.replace(".", ".");` you don't replace comma by dot , you're replacing dot by another dot

Comment: Now i'm doing this: `val = (value / 1).toFixed().replace(".", ",");` and the result is same @BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: ok good, did you try to console `val.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")`?

Comment: You mean this: `formatPrice(value) {
      let val = (value / 1).toFixed().replace(".", ",");
      return val.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","); //75.674,00

      val.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    },`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182674/discussion-between-boussadjra-brahim-and-saif-zakir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a typo, you have a property called `ct_Invoice_grand_total` in your `ctInvoice` object with uppercase **I** and you're calling it with lowercase *i*, so you should put :

```
     <tr v-for="ctInvoice in ctInvoices" :key="ctInvoice.id">
       <td>{{ formatPrice(ctInvoice.ct_Invoice_grand_total) }}</td>
     </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

What error does your console show?

In your data you are specifing `ctInvoices` as an object, shouldn't this be an array with `ctInvoice` objects in it?

Does every `ctInvoice` in the `ctInvoices` contain a `ct_invoice_grand_total` property?

Instead of using a function to format the price, you could use an filter with [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

```
Vue.filter('formatNumber', value => {
    let number = parseFloat(value);
    let options = { minimumFractionDigits: 2, style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' };

    return number.toLocaleString("nl-NL", options);
});
```